# Como eu faço para meu aplicativo aparecer no menu (compartilhar via) do android?

Tags: android, android-intent

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com faço pro meu aplicativo aparecer nessa tela?

Answer (score 2):

Tem de adicionar à declaração da Activity no AndroidManifest.xml um [`<intent-filter>`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element) que inclua a *action* [ACTION_SEND](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND) e o tipo de conteúdo que ela tratará.

Exemplo para conteúdo do tipo texto:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Para mais informações ver [Receiving simple data from other apps.](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive)